# Amazon Alexa Entity Resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am having trouble getting Alexa to understand any synonyms for the words I'm speaking to her. She will always return that she does not know the meaning of the synonym despite having added it as part of the intent schema:

```
{
  "languageModel": {
    "types": [
      {
        "name": "LIST_OF_DEFINITIONS",
        "values": [
          {
            "id": "USER_EXPERIENCE",
            "name": {
              "value": "user experience",
              "synonyms": [
                "ux"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
      "samples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
      "samples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "AMAZON.RepeatIntent",
      "samples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
      "samples": []
    },
    {
      "name": "RecipeIntent",
      "samples": [
        "what is a {Definition}"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Definition",
          "type": "LIST_OF_DEFINITIONS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "invocationName": "digital dictionary"
 }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your synonym "ux" isn't going to be understood because the user won't pronounce it like a word but rather they will say two letters. So, try adding "u x" and "U.X.". That should work.

Comment: I left UX in there as an example. Synonyms aren't working at all for other words. So if I have 'Agile working' the synonym 'agile' is not recognised